# Hadoop Hive: create external table with dynamic location

Tags: hive

I am trying to create a Hive external table that points to an S3 output file.
The file name should reflect the current date (it is always a new file).

I tried this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_export (...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION concat('s3://BlobStore/Exports/Daily_', from_unixtime(unix_STRING(),'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

but I get an error:
FAILED: Parse Error: line 3:9 mismatched input 'concat' expecting StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification

is there any way to dynamically specify table location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found the hive variables feature.
So I pass the location in the cli as follows

```
hive -d s3file=s3://BlobStore/Exports/APKsCollection_test/`date +%F`/
```

and then use the variable in the hive command

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_export (...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${s3File}';
```

Comment: Good. You can mark this as accepted if it is working the way you need, so that others can benefit from it. Thank you.

Comment: single quotes around the variable name in hql made it work, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This function doesn't work at my side , 
how did you make this happen ?

```
hive -d s3file=s3://BlobStore/Exports/APKsCollection_test/`date +%F`/
```